# htaccess doesn't rewrite all rules

Tags: .htaccess

The .htaccess file ignores the first rule

The url should be http://example.com/public_html/folder/file.php

```
# Rewrite all to public_html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php/
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/$1
# URL: http://example.com/public_html/folder/file

# Hide/Add .php from/to URL
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php/
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php
# URL: http://example.com/folder/file.php
```

Comment: @anubhava the public_html folder is the website and the php folder is the backend stuff

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` oath?

Comment: @anubhava you mean the root directory?

Comment: @anubhava /Users/gus/sites/New/8888/goestav5

Comment: ok, so `http://example.com/public_html/` opens a valid page on your website?

Comment: @anubhava yes, the index page (I updated the code because I forgot a line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way inside `/Users/gus/sites/New/8888/goestav5/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore all php/ URIs
RewriteRule ^php/ - [L,NC]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# rewrite every non-file, non-directory to public_html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!public_html/)(.*)$ public_html/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: You mean `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` right?